# Enviar notificãção ao vivo sem se repetir

Tags: javascript, push-notification

Estou com um código, que desejo fazer um sistema de notificação em push ao vivo, aqui está meu código:

```
  <script>
        Notification.requestPermission();
        function requisitar(){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else 
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            var text=xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==20)
            {
                var notification = new Notification("Site DaviDEV", {
                    icon: 'http://i.imgur.com/cWk851f.png',
                    body: text
                });
                notification.onclick = function() {
                    window.open("<?php echo $url; ?>");
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/notificacao/notificacao.txt",true);
        xmlhttp.send();



    }

    window.setInterval(requisitar, 1000);
    </script>
```

Mais ele consegue ler o arquivo e mandar a notificação, mais tem um problema: Ele fica mandando varias notificações, tipo um spam, quero alguma coisa que so mande uma pra cada pessoa, oque posso fazer?

Comment: O motivo do "Spam" é o `window.setInterval`, tente removelo ou usar um `window.setTimeout`... apenas não entendi pq utilizar `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` quando o Browser é recente o suficiente para disponibilizar a Notification API.

Comment: Mais eu quero ao vivo, por exeplo eu editei o texto lá, todo mundo vê. depois some, se eu editar de novo ele vai e anuncia o novo.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta? o que queres dizer com "editei o texto lá"? ( e já agora, acho que queres ter 200 aqui `xmlhttp.status==20)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar utilizar alguma lógica para identificar o usuário e se você já enviou a mensagem para ele no servidor. A maneira mais simples seria armazenar uma lista de ips e verificar se você esta

e ao invés de utilizar um pooling do lado cliente uma implementação melhor seria utilizar websockets.

Você pode implementar o websocket por si mesmo utilizando socket.io ou utilizar algum serviço pago estilo [elasticpush.com](http://elasticpush.com) para se comunicar com os clientes sem utilizar pooling.